# How to send data over HTTP(S) to an Android application

Tags: android, http, service, server, push-notification

I am very new to Android App development and I have to execute a very simple use case. I have a service and I want it to send some data to my android app. This data for simplicity can be a JSON object with a text field like so:

```
{"text": "Hello world"}
```

And in the app, when this message is received, I want to display "Hello world". So every time a request is sent from the service, I want the message to be updated on the app. How can I accomplish this? All the documentation available on the internet focuses on making calls to the service. I want to make a call to the Android app. Thank you

Comment: You should look at [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging). [Amazon SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/), or another push messaging service.

Comment: Concretely, what is such a piece of code called on the application side? For example I would use Volley to make a request to an external API. What can I use in Android to consume messages from SNS?

Comment: I've honestly never used SNS, I was just providing options, so I couldn't tell you.  For FCM, take a look at this guide: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Comment: That is genuinely very helpful. I wouldn't mind marking it as an accepted answer but I'd like to see if there are more inputs. Thanks again

Comment: I'm glad it helped!  I expanded on it a bit as an answer.  Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sending messages from the server to the app, you'd want to use a push messaging solution such as [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging), [Amazon SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/), or others.

Normally, it's difficult to send a message from a server to an app, because you can't simply open a connection to a device that's not set up as a server.  These services interact with a service that's already running on the device, such as Google Play Services on Android or Apple Push Notification Service on iOS, to deliver messages to the device on demand.

For an overview of how to set up Firebase Cloud Messaging in an Android app, check out the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client).

<sup>Disclosure: I work for Google, who make Firebase</sup>